# How to align a script after a div size for every resolution?

Tags: alignment

So i have this div containing a contact script:

```
<div id="contactbox" style="">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://www.response-o-    
 matic.com/mail.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">here's the script</form>


</div>

</div>
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to align a script after the wrapper size for every resolution.Because i set the position of the script in percentage and on my resolution it looks centered in wrapper.But on a bigger resolution for example it's not working,it's a little bit in left side,that means the script goes after the html size because it focuses after it and it goes in the middle.
I know that if i set the wrapper with:

```
 .wrapper
  {
   text-align:center;
  }
```

then every texts from the wrapper will be centered after his size,but with scripts isnt working.So is there any way?